# An efficient way of reading integers from file

Tags: c

I'd like to read all integers from a file into the one list/array. All numbers are separated by space (one or more) or end line character (one or more). What is the most efficient and/or elegant way of doing this? Functions from c++ library are prohibited.

I did it this way:

```
/* We assume that 'buffer' is big enaugh */
int i = 0;
while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &buffer[i]) != EOF) {
    ++i;
}
```

Sample data:

```
1   2     3
 4 56
    789         
9          91 56   

 10 
11
```

Comment: Call `fscanf()` in a loop.

Comment: Please show what you tried. We don't do your homework for you.

Comment: Please show some code as an indication that you have tried something.

Comment: `!= EOF` should read `== 1`. Otherwise you code goes into an infinite loop if it contains something that's not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code is close.  Test against `1` rather than `EOF` so code does not get caught in a endless loop should non-numeric data occur.  I'd use a `for()` loop, but `while` is OK too.

Note that `"%d"` directs `fscanf()` to first scan and discard any white-space including `' '` and `'\n'` before looking for sign and digits.

```
#define N 100
int buffer[N];
int i,j;

for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &buffer[i]) != 1) {
    break;
  }
}

for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
  printf("buffer[%d] --> %d\n", j, buffer[j]);
}
```

Comment: Note:  scanf with `%d` causes undefined behaviour (C11 7.21.6.2/10) if the input contains a number that doesn't fit in `int`. (Same problem `atoi` has).  For toy programs this is usually overlooked but in production you would not use this (and probably not use `scanf` at all).

Comment: So maybe you would like to provide better solution?

Comment: @Matt McNabb `scanf()/fscanf()/sscanf()/atoi` have various strengths and weaknesses - agree especially `scanf()` - but that is not used here.  `strtol` and family (yet missing `strtoi`) have their pit-falls too  with typical code not well handling `errno/endptr/type` properly.`strtol()` has its quirks _always_ allowing `0x` with base 16 and locale specific options.  Complete functional control may be had with custom conversions, yet that comes with its price of unproven correctness, efficiency  and development costs.  Its all about balancing these issues and more.

Comment: @chux by "scanf" I mean the scanf family , they all have the same specification other than where they get the input from

Comment: @Matt McNabb  True the have many similarities.   Differences include: `sscanf()` never scans `'\0'`.  This is particularly important with `"%[]"`.  `fscanf()` with certain devices (serial interfaces) does not reliably  `unget()` more than 1 `char`: this is noticeable when scanning "+-x" into `"%d"`. With `fscanf()/sscanf()`, code can rewind as needed, not so with `scanf()`.   Other subtleties exist too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets` to read each line from the file into a string, say `char *line` .

Then you can loop through that string char by char and use `isDigit` to determine if the character is a digit or not.

To read numbers with more than one digit place each digit in a string and use `atoi` to convert them to an integer

Comment: `strtok()` would be better than reading it character by character.

Comment: I agree but I think this is probably a programming assignment and the OP is a beginner with C. I might be wrong though. In any case, strtok is indeed a better practice

Comment: `strtok` is generally a poor choice IMHO as it is not re-entrant, and code with multiple strtok calls gets ugly fast